# BeautifulSoup find not working in threadworker

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This code works fine in python3 and the print command shows the webside page conten which has benn loaed through urllib.request.urlopen und forwarded to the function. However when function is called in threadworker after print the for loops doens't bring back any information.

```
def meta_data(page_result):
    _side = {
            'expires': '',
            'generator': ''
           }
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_result, "lxml")

    print(soup)
    # get meta infos
    for tag in soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'name': 'expires'}):
        if 'content' in str(tag):
            tag = str(tag)
            tag = str(tag.split('"')[1:2])
            tag = clean_string(tag)
            _side['expires'] = tag

    for tag in soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'name': 'generator'}):
        if 'content' in str(tag):
            tag = str(tag)
            tag = str(tag.split('"')[1:2])
            tag = clean_string(tag)
            _side['generator'] = tag

    return _side
```

is there any explenation ?